# how can I copy two folders into another

Tags: python, file, copy

I have wrote a program in Python, that should copy two folders into another folder.
At the Internet, I saw the method copytree, from the library shutil.
But it just works with ine file. What can I do, if I want to have more Folders to copy?

```
pfad2 = "C:\\Users\\...\\source\\repos\\Bilder in csv deeplearning\\Bilder in csv deeplearning\\downloads\\" + wort2 
shutil.copytree(pfad1, "C:\\Users\\...\\source\\repos\\Bilder in csv deeplearning\\Bilder in csv deeplearning\\fertig")
```

Thats what I wrote.

Comment: Please add what you have done so far

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well you have:

1. destination dir - `dir`
2. source dir to copy into `dir` - `src1`
3. source dir to copy into `dir` - `src2`

The result should be:

```
dir:
|- src1
|- src2
```

You can only do it in two steps (copy one directory at a time).
Notice that `shutil.copytree` `dest` parameter must not exist, so I would recommend the following code:

```
import pathlib    
import shutil
dest_dir = pathlib.Path('path/to/destination')
src_dir1 = pathlib.Path('path/to/first/directory/to/copy')
src_dir2 = pathlib.Path('path/to/second/directory/to/copy')
shutil.copytree(str(src_dir1), str(dest_dir / src_dir1.name))
shutil.copytree(str(src_dir2), str(dest_dir / src_dir2.name))
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. It works. But can you please explaine why?

Comment: If you can add your full code and the exception I could help you understand why it didn't work and why it works here

Comment: What of code do you need exactly? Ist a little bigger project, and I dont think its helpful to post all code.